# Tower of Hanoi Variation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, puzzle

There are four pegs, numbered from 0 to 3.  A stack of n white disks, is initially on peg 0, and a stack of n black disks, initially on peg 2.  The destination pegs for the white stack and the black stack are pegs 2 and 0, respectively.  In other words, the goal is to interchange the two stacks, using pegs 1 and 3 as temporary holding pegs.

The basic way to solve is that first we move the white disks initially to peg 1 using peg 3 as temporary holding peg (using regular tower of Hanoi problem). And then move black disks to peg 0 using peg 3, finally move white disks from peg 1 to peg 2. Is there any better way to solve this in lesser number of steps? The above approach gives $3*2^n -3$ steps.

Comment: Can white and black disks be stacked together?

Comment: This is "puzzle 1" from [www.cs.wm.edu](https://www.cs.wm.edu/~pkstoc/greece.pdf), where they show a lower bound of $2^{n+1}-1$ is optimal.

Comment: Yes black and white disks can be stacked together provided that the size of the one above is strictly greater than the one below.